# How to attached scrollbar to frame inside labelframe

Tags: python, tkinter

I have these few lines of code here which have placed `frame` inside `labelframe` and i want to attached `scrollbar` to the `frame` for the listbox to scroll.

Th scrollbar doesn't attache well to the `frame` and the `listbox` it below the `listbox`. I have searched on this site and all the answers are required that the `scrollbar` should be attached to the `frame` have done that and am not getting thee desire result.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")


lab = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="MY LABELFRAME")
lab.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

 # this is the frame i have created to insert the listbox
fr = tk.Frame(lab, width=200, height=200, bg="brown")
fr.place(x=100, y=100)


list1 = tk.Listbox(fr, width=20, height=15)
list1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(fr, orient='vertical')
scrollbar.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT)
list1.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.configure(command=list1.yview)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you want the scrollbar on the right and the listbox on the left, have you considered trying to explicitly pack the listbox on the left?

Comment: i want the listbox inside the frame

Comment: the frame should be where it is.

Comment: I never suggested moving the listbox out of the frame.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the listbox on the left and the scrollbar on the right, that is exactly how you should pack them. By not explicitly setting a side, `pack` is going to put the listbox at the top of the frame, leaving room only at the bottom for the scrollbar.

The solution is to explicitly give the `side` attribute when packing the listbox:

```
list1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, side="left")
```

It's a bit hard to see in the following screenshot since the scrollbar isn't active, but you can just make out the fact that the scrollbar is to the right of the listbox.

[image]